# Swift - function with many params that need to be added to url query params

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

Im building a swift package that will be a wrapper to an api. Since its going to be used by many people with many different needs, I have to fully support what the api offers.

There are 10 different query parameters all of which are optional to make the network request. I have a couple different ways of doing this, but I want to see if there is an optimal way im unaware of.

```
// only showing 3 params but I have 10 optional params
func getData(query: String, limit: Int, page: Int) {
    let url: String = "https://baseurl.com"
    if let query = query {
        url += "?query=\(query)"
    }
    if let limit = limit {
        url += "?limit=\(limit)"
    }
    // do this for all 10 query params
    // make network request with url
}
```

next option was something like creating an object for my params but i think id be in the same position for unpacking the data

```
struct Params {
    var query: String?
    var limit: Int?
    var page: Int
    
    func createStringFromParams() -> String {
        let queryParams: String = ""
        if let query = query {
            url += "?query=\(query)"
        } 
        // do this for all params
    }
}

var params: Params()
params.query = "my query"
func getData(params: Params) {
    var url: String = "https://baseurl.com/\(params.createStringFromParams())"
}
```

I also will be doing this for many different functions as every api endpoint has 0-many query params.

Comment: I believe [URLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents) will be helpful  here

Comment: I'd use `URLQueryItem` & `URLComponents` as suggested in previous comment. Currently, if you have query AND limit, you should add a `&` and no question mark. If the values are limited, you can either have a big `query: String? = nil, limit: String? = nil` etc, or you could use a `enum` with associated values to handle all this, and have only one parameters: an array of that enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `URLQueryItem` & `URLComponents`.

Basic code being:

```
let baseUrl: String = "https://baseurl.com/"
var components = URLComponents(string: baseUrl)
let queryParameters = [URLQueryItem(name: "query", value: "myQuery")]
//If empty and set, it will add a "?" at the end of the URL, start of the query with no parameters
if !queryParameters.isEmpty {
    components?.queryItems = queryParameters
}
let finalURL = components?.url
```

Now, since you want to limit the values/calls, you could use an enum with associated values:

```
enum Params {
    case query(String)
    case limit(Int)
    case page(Int)
    
    func queryItem() -> URLQueryItem {
        switch self {
        case .limit(let limit):
            return URLQueryItem(name: "limit", value: "\(limit)")
        case .page(let page):
            return URLQueryItem(name: "page", value: "\(page)")
        case .query(let query):
            return URLQueryItem(name: "page", value: query)
        }
    }

}

func createURL(with params: [Params]) {
    let baseUrl: String = "https://baseurl.com/"
    var components = URLComponents(string: baseUrl)
    
    //If empty and set, it will add a "?" at the end of the URL, start of the query with no parameters
    if !queryParameters.isEmpty {
        components?.queryItems = queryParameters.map { $0.queryItem() }
    }
    
    let finalURL = components?.url
    print(finalURL!.absoluteString)
}
```

If you still want to use your parameter struct:

```
struct Params {
    let query: String?
    let limit: Int?
    let page: Int?
    
    
    init(query: String? = nil, limit: Int? = nil, page: Int? = nil) {
        self.query = query
        self.limit = limit
        self.page = page
    }
    
    func queryItems() -> [URLQueryItem] {
        var items: [URLQueryItem] = []
        if let query = query {
            items.append(URLQueryItem(name: "query", value: query))
        }
        
        if let limit = limit {
            items.append(URLQueryItem(name: "limit", value: "\(limit)"))
        }
        
        if let page = page {
            items.append(URLQueryItem(name: "page", value: "\(page)"))
        }
        
        return items
    }
}

func createURL(with params: Params) {
    let baseUrl: String = "https://baseurl.com/"
    var components = URLComponents(string: baseUrl)
    
    //If empty and set, it will add a "?" at the end of the URL, start of the query with no parameters
    let queryParameters = params.queryItems()
    if !queryParameters.isEmpty {
        components?.queryItems = queryParameters
    }
    
    let finalURL = components?.url
    print(finalURL!.absoluteString)
}
```

In my opinion, both approach are valid. There are just less `if let` in the `enum` solution.

Comment: Also, the valid alternative would be to use encoder for URLQueryParameters, like this: https://github.com/kylehughes/URLQueryItemCoder (or any other)

Comment: Thank you Larme, This is good stuff. Put as accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

As Joakim and Larme suggest in their comments, you should build your URL using an URLComponents object. You give it the various components of your URL and it builds the URL string for you, including applying the appropriate escaping for each part of the URL (some characters like "=", "&" and "?" are legal in other parts of the URL but not in the query parameters, as an example of the special-case escaping it does.) It is a smart object and handles a lot of the messy edge cases for you.

Defining an enum with cases for the different URL components and associated values to hold the contents of each component (as suggested by Larme) is interesting. You'd then pass an array of these enums to your function.